# how to auto launch iOS app when connected to external accessories?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, mfi, eaaccessory

Coming straight to the topic, I am developing an app where I have kept an option for user to select autolaunch. If user selects, then only app will auto launch when respected external accessory is connected via Bluetooth. As soon any iOS device which is already paired comes in range of accessory, iOS app should auto launch. 
Approches already tried.

[Re-post: iOS modify App auto launch when iPhone is connected to external accessory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216713/re-post-ios-modify-app-auto-launch-when-iphone-is-connected-to-external-accesso)

Please help me in understanding, why we cant auto launch even if we have permission of user and if we can do then what is the method in steps programatically.

Comment: Is your device MFi certified?  Have you added the device protocol to your info.plist?  What is happening when you pair the device?

Comment: @paulw Yes we are certified, and i have already added protocols in info.plist, if possible can you please provide me how to handle autolaunch in terms of session and background mode also.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734222/how-to-launch-an-iphone-app-when-an-external-accessory-is-either-paired-over-bt